# How do I count unique values in JSON with a Jora query

Tags: json, jora

Given an array like below, how do I count the occurrences of each "fruit" type with a [Jora](https://github.com/discoveryjs/jora) query?

```
[
    {"fruit": "apple"},
    {"fruit": "orange"},
    {"fruit": "banana"},
    {"fruit": "banana"},
    {"fruit": "apple"},
    {"fruit": "apple"}
]
```

I'm looking for an answer like this:

```
[
    {"fruit": "apple", "count": 3},
    {"fruit": "orange", "count": 1},
    {"fruit": "banana", "count": 2}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query gets you the answer your looking for:

```
group(<fruit>).({fruit: key, count: value.size()})
```

or more explicitely, including implicit selectors:

```
@.group(<$.fruit>).map(<{"fruit": $.key, "count": $.value.size()}>)
```

To break it down, we're first using the `group()` [method](https://github.com/discoveryjs/jora#build-in-methods), passing it the "function" (the angle brackets `<>`) of a selector for `fruit`. Note that we can omit the implicit query input selector `@.` which could precede the method call and the implicit scope selector `$.` in the `fruit` selector.

So `group(<fruit>)` gives us a result of:

```
[
    { "key": "apple", "value": [{…}, {…}, {…}] },
    { "key": "orange", "value": [{…}] },
    { "key": "banana", "value": [{…}, {…}] }
]
```

We can then use the `map()` method or the parenthesis overload for map `.()`, with an object definition of the result we're looking for `{fruit: key, count: value.size()}`, to create a new array giving the count or `.size()` of the `value` array in the result from `group()`.

---

This was enough of a struggle for me, and [Jora](https://github.com/discoveryjs/jora) is new enough with limited documentation that I thought to ask and answer this might be of help to someone.

Comment: Please note that `<expr>` is deprecated syntax for a function definition. You should use  `=>expr` syntax instead.